# KivyMD Toolbar left_action_items can't switch screens?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, toolbar, kivymd

I am new to KivyMD and presently working on MDToolbar. I learned to add left_action_items onto the toolbar. But my question is how to use those action_items to change screens, ie when I click those action_items it should go to a different screen, that's what they are used for right(change screens). I checked dozens of solutions on the internet including StackOverflow, but none of them helped me. Can someone help me rectify this issue.....

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
MDToolbar:
    title: 'Menu'
    left_action_items: [['icon_button', lambda _: setattr(root.manager, 'current', 'screen_to_move_to')]]
```

This is the alternative syntax to change the screens through buttons on MDToolbar, notice the `lambda_:setattr()` with parameters root.manager, the current screen, and the target screen.